# Antonym for "recent", as in time series observations

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I do time series analysis and forecasting, and many algorithms weight more recent observations more highly than observations from the more distant past in extrapolating.

The previous sentence already illustrates my conundrum: is there a one-word antonym for "recent" which I could use in lieu of the cumbersome "from the more distant past"? I did think about

> many forecasting algorithms weight more recent observations more highly than more distant observations

but that doesn't sound quite right. A coauthor has suggested "distal", but the OED sees this only in a location-related sense.

Comment: If 'recent' is held in mind, 'earlier' works. If not, the comparative doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Many forecasting algorithms weight recent observations more highly than* ***older*** *ones.*"

(Or just "*... higher than ...*.")

Answer (score 2):

[Removed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/removed) can be considered:

> separate or remote in space, time, or character

*Prior* and *later* are also possibilities. Plain but clear.

It depends somewhat on the technical jargon of your field. But I would agree that [distal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distal) has a specific connotation of further away in location than in time, where distant is more common.

Answer (score 1):

Consider "more *remote* observations", motivated by @medica's [dictionary entry](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/318568/142322).

> **Remote** *adjective*
>   1.2 Distant in time: *a golden age in the remote past*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/remote)

Here's an example in an academic setting:

> The adjacent data points still showed considerably high loadings,
>   but loadings decreased sharply for more remote data points.
>   [- p217, footnote 3, Kayser et al, Event-related potentials ERPs to hemifield presentations of emotional stimuli](http://psychophysiology.cpmc.columbia.edu/pdf/Kayser2000a.pdf)